# request as been blocked by CORS:Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status

Tags: reactjs, react-native, cors

Im doing this request:

```
 saveNewPermissions=(newGroupPermissions,curentGroupId)=>{
    window.alert(this.baseUrl+"/addPermission/group/"+curentGroupId)
    return fetch(this.baseUrl+"/addPermission/group/"+curentGroupId, {
        method: 'PUT',
        headers: {
            'Accept': 'application/json',
            'Content-Type': 'application/json',
        },
        body: JSON.stringify({
            permissions: newGroupPermissions
        })
    })
}
```

But i got the follwoing error when the method is executed:
*Access to fetch at 'http://localhost:8083/uaa/addPermission/group/2' from origin 'http://localhost:3000' has been blocked by CORS policy: Response to preflight request doesn't pass access control check: It does not have HTTP ok status.*
I already a have the CORS Chrome pluggin and i can do other types of request like posts and gets and the method that receives the request has the @CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true").The method is in java using springboot.

Comment: Your server api has to enable CORS, it has nothing to do with your client or browser

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I was using the @CrossOrigin with the default arguments which are just the get and post, thats why the put wasn´t working you need to put:

```
@CrossOrigin(allowCredentials = "true",methods = {RequestMethod.GET, RequestMethod.POST, RequestMethod.PUT})
```